# System.Func passed in to a linq where method without enumerating

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a method where I am trying to return all default customer addresses with the matching gender. I would like to be able to build up the filtering query bit by bit by passing in System.Func methods to the where clause.

```
    var emailAddresses = new List<string>();

        // get all customers.
        IQueryable<Customer> customersQ = base.GetAllQueryable(appContext).Where(o => o.Deleted == false);

        // for each customer filter, filter the query.

        var genders = new List<string>() { "C" };

        Func<Customer, bool> customerGender = (o => genders.Contains(o.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsDefaultAddress).Gender));
        customersQ = customersQ.Where(customerGender).AsQueryable();


        emailAddresses = (from c in customersQ
                          select c.Email).Distinct().ToList();

        return emailAddresses;
```

But this method calls the database for every address (8000) times which is very slow.

however if I replace the two lines

```
    Func<Customer, bool> customerGender = (o => genders.Contains(o.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsDefaultAddress).Gender));
        customersQ = customersQ.Where(customerGender).AsQueryable();
```

with one line

```
    customersQ = customersQ.Where(o => genders.Contains(o.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsDefaultAddress).Gender)).AsQueryable();
```

Then the query only makes one call to the database and is very fast.

My question is why does this make a difference? How can I make the first method work with only calling the database once?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use expression instead of Func:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> customerGender = (o => 
   genders.Contains(o.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsDefaultAddress).Gender));
customersQ = customersQ.Where(customerGender).AsQueryable();
```

When you are using simple `Func` delegate, then `Where` extension of [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) is called. Thus all data goes into memory, where it is enumerated and lambda is executed for each entity. And you have many calls to database.

On the other hand, when you are using expression, then `Where` extension of [`Queryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx) is called, and expression is converted into SQL query. That's why you have single query in second case (if you use in-place lambda it is converted into expression).